# Python PyDrive No downloadLink/exportLinks

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive

I'm using [pyDrive](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/) library, and now I need to get xmls file and read it but I have an error

> pydrive.files.FileNotDownloadableError: No downloadLink/exportLinks
>   for mimetype found in metadata

**white_list_xmls** - my xmls file

My code:

```
tmp_name = None
with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix='.xlsx') as tf:
   tf.write(white_list_xmls.GetContentFile(white_list_xmls['title']))
      tf.flush()
      tmp_name = tf.name
   if tmp_name is not None:
      print(tmp_name)
```

then I change the code like this:

```
    tmp_name = None
                with NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix='.xlsx') as tf:
                    mimetypes = {
                        'application/vnd.google-apps.document': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
                        'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet': 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'
                    }
                    if white_list_xmls['mimeType'] in mimetypes:
                        download_mimetype = mimetypes[white_list_xmls['mimeType']]
                        tf.write(white_list_xmls.GetContentFile(white_list_xmls['title'], mimetype=download_mimetype))
                        tf.flush()
                        tmp_name = tf.name
                if tmp_name is not None:
print(tmp_name)
```

but I have an error too:

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'NoneType'

Comment: Quick question. What's your program trying to do? What's your expected to outcome?

Comment: @noogui my programm try download file from link and read this file(xmls)